# xmppframework iphone Unable to add users to already created room (group chat)

Tags: iphone, xcode, xmppframework

I'm trying for group chat in iphone,am able to use single chat successfully.

I have created new room using following code successfully.

```
XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage *rosterstorage = [[XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage alloc] init];
XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:rosterstorage jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"viratsroom@conference.praveens-mac-mini.local"] dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppRoom activate:[[self appDelegate] xmppStream]];
if ([xmppRoom preJoinWithNickname:@"viratsRoom"]) {
  NSLog(@"room created");
  [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"viratsroom11" history:nil];
}
[xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
[xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:[self appDelegate] delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

now under users in this group there is one user shown on openfire server which is correct.
my questions are,
1)where and how to handle invitation message to join group?
2)I have tried to join the same group made above by using following code

```
XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage *rosterstorage = [[XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage alloc] init];
XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:rosterstorage jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"viratsroom@conference.praveens-mac-mini.local"] dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom activate:[[self appDelegate] xmppStream]];
[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"viratsroom11" history:nil];
[xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
[xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:[self appDelegate] delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

the room name now is shown in my offline users list.
now users under this room on openfire server should increase to two as one more user has joined this room but it still shows only one previous user member.

Am I missing something? any mistake in code ? please help!
Thanks .

Comment: i am getting error in "if ([xmppRoom preJoinWithNickname:@"viratsRoom"]) {"

Comment: @virata can you please upload the demo code. i am unable to create the group with same code. I have successfully integrated one-to-one chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this,
Room wasnt configured properly hence all problems
calling this immediately after creating room doesnt work-

```
[xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm]; 
[xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];
```

it takes a little time to create room after that u can configure the room.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(ConfigureNewRoom:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

:)

Comment: Thank you for sharing info, really appreciate. I am Mohit and I am currently working on XMPP for one of my project. I have managed to implement one to one chat, and now I need to implement Group chat which I can see you have already done. I am wondering if you guide me in how to create a room and share your group chat knowledge with me. Any small code will help me alot. I am under pressure and kind words of knowledge and code will help me alot.

Comment: @virata: Thanks for the answer. It helped me. Wanted to give a suggestionn This approach does work but its bit like a hack as we are not sure actually how much time configuring a room will take. Rather than that we can call the method `configureRoomUsingOptions:` in method `- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchConfigurationForm:(NSXMLElement *)configForm` which is a delegate method of class XMPPRoom and gets called after completion of room configuration.